# gulp-svg2png is not working and giving UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error

Tags: gulp, npm-scripts

gulp-svg2png is not working and giving the following error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
I did research on this site and on google also found this question relevant to my situation exactly but there is no correct answer for that
[UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning with svg2png from svg-sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49377675/10209855)

any help would be highly appreciated.
here is my task file

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprite'),
    svg2png = require('gulp-svg2png');

// var config consist of mode we used, and it used the css mode
var config = {
    mode: {
        css: {
            sprite: 'sprite.svg',
            render: {
                css: {
                    template: './gulp/template/sprite.css'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

gulp.task('createSprite', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/assets/images/icons/**/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgSprite(config))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./app/temp/sprite/"));
});

gulp.task('createPngCopy', ['createSprite'], function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/temp/sprite/css/*.svg')
    .pipe(svg2png())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/temp/sprite/css'));
});

gulp.task('sprite', ['createSprite', 'createPngCopy']);
```

my working environment is as follows

- node = v8.6.0
- npm  = v5.3.0
- gulp = cli v2.0.1 local v3.9.1
- gulp-svg2png = v2.0.2